# datastax exterprise - issues while reading with local one

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We have two tables with replication factor 3. We write in batches to both tables, the same data.  We write with LOCAL_QUORUM.

When we read with LOCAL_ONE we get different results for data written months ago. If we read with LOCAL_QUORUM it's fine.

From what I understand eventually consistent means that the data wrote in the last seconds might not be consistent .. but 
not the data older than months.

Comment: Hey Dan, can you share your schemas and queries to give us a better idea of what's going on? While Cassandra is an eventually consistent system, inconsistencies usually mean a larger problem. Cassandra replicates in microseconds - if it takes seconds for all replicas to get the data, something is very wrong.

Comment: do you ever run `nodetool repair`? It's still a recommended practice afaik. also are your nodes synced up wrt time? the times should be the same within a few millis. otherwise writes can get messed up and older data can appear to be newer because of a bad timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Of course, the issues was caused by not running regular repairs.